# Error conversion in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexof

I'm trying to to find the index of an item in an array, the array contains items of a struct I've created called TreeItem, but I keep getting the following error everytime I try to call it.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'TreeItem' to expected argument type
'@noescape (TreeItem) throws -> Bool'
```

Can you help me out guys.

Edited (Code Added):
in a separate file the struct is defined: 
    import Foundation

```
struct TreeItem {

var Name = String()
var Parent = String()
var HasSons : Bool = false
var Expanded : Bool = false
var Status : Int = 0
init( Parent: String?, Name: String?,HasSons: Bool?, Expanded : Bool?,Status : Int )
{
    self.Name = Name!
    self.Parent=Parent!
    self.HasSons = HasSons!
    self.Expanded = Expanded!
    self.Status = Status
}
```

}

in the view controller:

```
var ExpenseCategoryItems = [TreeItem]()
//Fill array with data

func ToggleDeleteButtonStateFunc(){
var TreeSample : TreeView = SomeData
var x = ExpenseCategoryItems.indexOf(TreeSample)
}
```

In that last line of code the crash keeps happening.

Comment: Please post some code. It's hard to find where error is without code.

Comment: give code fragment where it crash

Comment: var x = ExpenseCategoryItems.indexOf(TreeSample)

Answer (score 0):

If you post the code we can give you a better answer.

Without the code, here is a guess: you may be missing `Equatable` for the struct and a suitable function to decide if two structs are equal.

```
struct TreeItem:Equatable {
    var someProperty:String!
}

func ==(lhs: TreeItem, rhs: TreeItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.someProperty == rhs.someProperty 
}
```

Adjust the `==` function as needed for your struct.